# How can I change the background of a NSTableColumn?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to change the background of specific columns in my NSTableView (on mac).

Should I change it at column level or cell level?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the color for each of the cells in that column. Something kind of like:

```
- (NSView*)tableView:(NSTableView*)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn*)tableColumn
              row:(NSInteger)row
{
    //make cell
    ...
    if([tableColumn.identifier isEqual:@(0))
    {
        cellView.drawsBackground = YES;
        cellView.backgroundColor = [NSColor lightGrayColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I still have a question: how do I restore the original colors? I can't just set the previous color because the tableview has a sort of grid colors: http://cl.ly/image/1z0X0M2l3k3H